# How can I generate a random number for each row with condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new at Python and I'll appreciate your help.

I have a data frame with 2000 rows and 2 columns: Row and Pct.
Basically, I want to create a third column that will be based on the following logic:

1. To generate a random number (between 0 to 1) for the first row - let's call this number X
2. If  X>Pct I want to add 1 to the new column and generate an additional random number for the first row and check again if X>Pct and if so - add 1 to the new column and generate an additional random number and so on.....
3. If X<=Pct I want to add 1 to the new column and move on to the next row, and so on.

Hope I managed to explain myself :)

Thanks!

***Edit:***
For your questions:

1. It's just an example, I uploaded my df with a CSV file
2. Adding 1 -> It means that the new column is basically empty (zero) and if the condition is true I want to add 1 to the proper row. Basically it should act as a counter.

```
data = {
        'Pct': [0.8,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.3,1,0.23,0.75,0.93,0.6],
        'Row': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Row','Pct'])
df

    Row Pct
0   1   0.80
1   2   0.40
2   3   0.30
3   4   0.70
4   5   0.30
5   6   1.00
6   7   0.23
7   8   0.75
8   9   0.93
9   10  0.60
```

Comment: What's the inter intended output and what have you actually tried?

Comment: What do you mean by add 1? If X = 0.9 and Pct = 0.8, does the third column have value of 1, 1.9 or 1.8?

Comment: Please give an example walkthrough, the adding 1 part is not quite clear..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
def generate_random_values(row):
    pct_value = float(row['Pct'])
    # 1 . Generate random no bw 0 and 1
    x = np.random.random()
    # 2. Init value of new column
    new_col = 0
    # 3. while x > pct_value, add 1 to new_col and generate new random no
    while x > pct_value:
        new_col += 1
        x = np.random.random()
    # 4. Here x < = pct_value, add 1 to new col and return for the current row
    new_col += 1
    return new_col
```

And then:

```py
df['new_column'] = df.apply(func=generate_random_values, axis=1)
```

```py
print (df)
>>>
   Row   Pct  new_column
0    1  0.80           1
1    2  0.40           2
2    3  0.30           1
3    4  0.70           1
4    5  0.30           8
5    6  1.00           1
6    7  0.23           1
7    8  0.75           1
8    9  0.93           1
9   10  0.60           2
```

Also might be a good idea to check for a minimum threshold for the 'Pct' column before running the above function as you don't want to run into an infinite loop...